# What is the proper way of adding a local dependency (openCV) in Meson?

Tags: opencv, meson-build

I am using OpenCV in one of my projects. Until now, I was using version 3 under Ubuntu 18.04, so in my `meson.build` I had:

```
... dependencies: [dependency('opencv')])
```

Now, I've compiled OpenCV 4 from source and installed to the default dir, `/usr/local/`, and changed my `meson.build` to:

```
... dependencies: [dependency('opencv4')])
```

Resulting in a not found error (despite this works with Ubuntu 20.04 and the package from the official repos, which is version 4.2). How should I specify the library's location so Meson can find it?

I've seen find_library, but that's deprecated according the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dependency` function is  using `pkg-config` or `cmake` if `pkg-config` fails, to find external dependency (installed library).

When you install `OpenCV4`, please check if there is `pkg-config` for opencv4. Here is my command:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep "opencv4"
```

and output:

```
opencv4 OpenCV - Open Source Computer Vision Library
```

Also, check `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. `pkg-config` will use that path to search for `.pc` files.

Edit:
be sure to use `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES` when building `opencv` with `cmake`.

Comment: Ok, so those commands return nothing, and $PKG_CONFIG_PATH seems empty. Should I try to create my own .pc file?

Comment: I seems that OpenCV [dropped pkg_config support](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154).

Comment: When compiling with `cmake`, did you set `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES` ?

Comment: So, I edited my answer to include part from the previous comment.